# Is it good practise to use Solr as DB

Tags: solr

I have seen Solr being used as a data store, literally as a Database. Can Solr be used in that capacity/ Is that the real purpose of Solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr 4.X is being marketed as NoSQL Search Server. It has features like Atomic updates, Versioning and Optimistic Concurrency, Durability, and Real-time Get which makes it suitable to be used as a NoSQL store. Prior versions i.e. Solr 3/2/1.X did not have some of the above features and was regarded primarily as a Search Server.

More details here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr4.0